# Semantic analysis for C language

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, semantic-analysis

I've been searching for a semantic analyzer for `C` language lately, but couldn't find any. I've found `flex` and `yacc` `C` language files to generate a parser. I've managed to modify them and generate a parser. But now i need to perform next step. I'll appreciate if someone could point me to some examples of semantic analysis for `C` and building the tree. Any information about semantic analysis will be helpful either. I've found some tiny `C` compilers but they use their own parsers so they doesn't suite me.

Comment: This link may help you : http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/louden/cmptext/

Answer (score 1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://wwww.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFreontEnd) probably provide what you need.

DMS provides general purpose parsing, tree building, and program analysis machinery.  The C front end specializes this for the C language.   It handles many common dialects/variants of C (GCC, Microsoft, Green Hills) with their dark corners, parses and builds ASTS, builds control and data flow graphs, points-to analysis as well as global call graphs accounting for indirect function  pointers.

You can try to do all of this yourself, but you'll find it takes man-years to get all this right.